# EditText and button(When button is pressed value shoud be entered in edittext field)

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-button

Am creating a calculator,i want when button is pressed for example say 5,how to set value 5 to the button and if that button is clicked . The value should be printed in edit text!!

**My source code:**

```
ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

gt=Double.parseDouble(ed.getText().toString());

ed.setText(""+gt);

}
```

Comment: full source code 

public void add(View view)
 {
 display();
 }
 private void display()
 {
 EditText ed;

> Button b;
 
double gt;

Comment: edit your question properly.

Answer (score 2):

**If** I understand your question correctly:

U got some buttons with text or digits.
And if someone presses one of those buttons u want to display the text of the button in your editText box?

If so u can do something like the following:

```
EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

Button myButton0= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button0);
myButton0.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Get the button text and display it in the editText
        //This will replace all text in the editText box
        myEditText.setText(myButton0.getText().toString());

        //Or (Thanks to @cherry-wave)
        //This will append the text, instead of replacing  
        myEditText.setText(myEditText.getText() + myButton0.getText().toString());
    }
});
```

**Or** (to handle all your buttons with only one method):
Add the following line to all your buttons in your layout xml:

```
 android:onClick="onClick"
```

And place the following method in your activity class file:

```
//Your onClick method
public void onClick(View v) {
    Button myButton = (Button)v;
    //Don't forget to declare your edittext
    //This will replace all text in the editText box
    myEditText.setText(myButton.getText().toString());

    //Or (Thanks to @cherry-wave)  
    //This will append the text, instead of replacing  
    myEditText.setText(myEditText.getText() + myButton.getText().toString());
}
```

Hope this helps u out.

Comment: In addition, when this is really about a calculator: First get the text of the edit text and then set the text & append the clicked buttons value

Comment: Good one! Added it to the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
    Take the value from button and add to edittext . 
    Just like this .
    editText.setText(btnFive.getText().toString());
Before button click get value from editText .
String edtValue = editText.getText.toString();
Than set  editText.setText(edtValue+btnFive.getText().toString());
```